# twitter login swift [TwitterKit] Error obtaining user auth token

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, twitter

login I have problem

2020-05-17 06:44:38.565714-0700 OuthFairbeass[3744:135615] [default] Failed to open URL twitterauth://authorize?consumer_key=5WnJxeILzBOa2ujeKFsbOiooz&consumer_secret=6EyBR9KvtO055Rrbt4EqM9oQW3xiZtxrR3alAjxkcRXyVlmjpW&oauth_callback=twitterkit-5WnJxeILzBOa2ujeKFsbOiooz&identifier=pzoIhelxQVsJcW5h0eUbduxjzw8Lr+fk8qFg6Xx6qtNeo6nTdPgprnMhLqbqqkrX: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=247, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}
2020-05-17 06:44:39.546329-0700 OuthFairbeass[3744:135619] Local time is off from UTC by -35995.546318 seconds
2020-05-17 06:44:39.546526-0700 OuthFairbeass[3744:135452] [TwitterKit] Error obtaining user auth token.
(lldb)

In the info plist, everything is fine. Also, enter the application on Twitter. Add Callback URLs
Special Firebase, but I do not know what the problem is, please help

```
       @IBAction func clickedLoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {

            TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in
                if session != nil{
                    let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
                    client.requestEmail { email, error in
                        if (email != nil) {
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
                        } else {
                            print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
                        }
            }


    }

}
```

here my file  info. plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbapi2016032888</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>twitterauth</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1462236107289657</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>OuthChat</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb146223610728</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>twitterkit-xeILzBOa2ujeKFsbOiz</string>
    </array>
        </dict>

    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>





    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

      FirebaseApp.configure()

 TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"xeILzBOa2ujeKFsbOiz", consumerSecret:"4EqM9oQW3xiZtxrR3alAjxkcRXyVlmjpW")
                     return true
    }

     func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
     }
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Twitter Kit (which is no longer supported) for authentication, not Firebase? Is this in the iOS simulator, or on the device? Does it open a web browser to offer the Twitter login screen?